# Cross section automation & overlay

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, visualisation, cross-section

I'm trying to automate and visualise the frequency and different type of road corridors along an existing route.

The route spans multiple kms and I'm trying to show the predominant types of corridor but also show key differences (e.g. a short bridge). The idea in my mind is to get cross sections every 5 m or so centralised on the road centre-line and overlay all of these onto a single image. Overlaid sections of line which show a darker colour, showing the increased frequency of this type of ground profile.

Is there a QGIS plugin or of something like this which exists?

I don't quite know where to start.

Comment: I removed your tag for and reference to Python because you have not presented any code.  In any event, I think you should eliminate OOTB and plug-in solutions before trying to write code.

Comment: Can you maybe draw an example image of what you want? I find it hard to visualize. By "profile" you mean soil profiles - images where the soil properties are drawn according to the depth at which they occur?